# What does 乐助 (yuè zhù) mean?

Tags: meaning

I think we've got some music biz jargon here:

[【我们恋爱吧 第二季】EP12](https://youtu.be/pdT22HeX504?t=1209) @ ～20:09

> [image]

The sentence:

> 我们的那个乐助说了

The person speaking often speaks of his band, so it is likely that 乐 is short for: 乐队. Of course, less specifically it could just be short for 音乐.

助 is a little more ambiguous. It could be 助唱, 助理 or something else.

It doesn't seem like a very common word. There aren't a lot of query hits for it online.

Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps, it's just simply 乐队助理. It's not uncommon for one to create his own abbreviation in day to day usage. (I can't see either YouTube, or the image OP posted)

Answer (score 1):

It is an abbreviation of the "musical assistant", 音乐, or 音效助理 at a music production studio.

Comment: So, 乐助 = 音乐助理? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is indicated in my answer 音乐助理 or 音效助理.